# Schengen visa overlapping problem?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, europe

I have a Schengen visa for December .. I have to apply another one for another country in October for job inquires! Is there a problem for my December visa?? Overlapping problem or something?? Thank you

Comment: **National visas** (Type D), for a job search, employment etc., is different than a **Schengen Visa** (Type C). Type C,D visas can coexist with each other.